# Cannot find cache named '' for CacheableOperation after application restart

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ehcache

To load data in EHCache while starting the application, i have configured bootstrapcacheloader and able to load the data for the first time. I am facing issue when I restart the application.Getting below error.

**Error** : "Cannot find cache named '' for CacheableOperation".

This is the cache I am loading the data, when application starts.

Note: I am not getting this error when I clean and restart application from Eclipse

Instead of cleaning the server every time, Please let me know if any configuration is required to clear all cache while stopping the server.

Comment: You need to share more information like configs and logs. But also describe better your problem as in its current form, possible answers would be guesses only.

Comment: I am modified code and set BootStrapCacheLoader to Cache instead of CacheManager. Cache is initialized , but getting below error.

Comment: [15 Aug 2015 12:55:34] [localhost-startStop-1] 24393  DEBUG (net.sf.ehcache.Cache:1183) :: Initialised cache: preLoadCache
start of load method in MyBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'preLoadCache' for CacheableOperation[public java.util.List com.repository.PreLoadCacheRepository.findAll()] caches=[preLoadCache] | key='' | condition='' | unless=''
 at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:161)